# Jira Groovy CreateSubtaskIssueLink parameter

Tags: groovy, jira

I am trying to create an Issue and subtask and link them. Here is the code fragment. The issues are created and stored but the link fails with

```
    // Create an empty issue
    MutableIssue parentObject = issueFactory.getIssue()
    parentObject.setProjectObject(project)
    parentObject.setReporter(reporter)
    parentObject.setIssueType(issueType)
    parentObject.setCustomFieldValue(pc, Double.valueOf(5))
    parentObject.setSummary(this.getSummary())
    Map params = new HashMap()
    params.put("issue", parentObject)
    Issue parentIssue = (Issue) issueManager.createIssueObject(reporter, params)

    // Get the subtask issuetype
    issueType = (issueTypeSchemeManager.getNonSubTaskIssueTypesForProject(project))[0]
    //Iterate through each project in the worklog map and create a subtask for each
    this.workLogMap.each {projectId, projectTime ->
        MutableIssue subtaskObject = issueFactory.getIssue()
        subtaskObject.setProjectObject(project)
        subtaskObject.setReporter(reporter)
        subtaskObject.setIssueType(issueType)
        subtaskObject.summary = ((ProjectTime) projectTime).getSummary(reporter.displayName)
        params.put("issue", subtaskObject)
        Issue subtask = (Issue) issueManager.createIssueObject(reporter, params)
        SubTaskManager.createSubTaskIssueLink(parentIssue, subtask, reporter)
    }
```

Fails with

```
No signature of method: static com.atlassian.jira.config.SubTaskManager.createSubTaskIssueLink() is applicable for argument types: (com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueImpl, com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueImpl, com.atlassian.jira.user.DelegatingApplicationUser)
```

The projectTime object is a local objectType that I iterate through to get worklog information.

Answer (score 2):

A stupid mistake (:-;) - I was using the class instead of the object - changed SubtaskManager (with capital S) to lower-case subtaskManager and it works.